# Receipt verification API for apps in Google Play Store

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-purchase-receipt

I am trying to use the payment verification API provided by Google using AWS Lambda.

Created a service account in Google Console and granted it permission for finance.
And I tried the test 48 hours later.

But the 401 error persists

<HttpError 401 when requesting https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/**.**.**/purchases/subscriptions/test1/tokens/realtokenvaluetest1?alt=json returned "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.". Details: "[{'message': 'The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.', 'domain': 'androidpublisher', 'reason': 'permissionDenied'}]">

Is it possible to test the payment receipt verification API if the status of the app currently under development in the Google Play Console is in a private test state?